# Replace NAs and empty string from dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset which contains numerical and nominal data. The numerical columns have NA and I'd like to replace those NAs with median. For nominal data I have just empty string "" I'd like them replaced with most occuring values. So far I got this:

```
replaceNA <- function(x) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    colMedian <- median(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  } else {
    colMax <- names(which.max(table(x)))
  }
}
```

How can I check every column and replace NAs and ""?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
replaceNA <- function(x) {
             v1 <- if(is.numeric(x))
                     median(x, na.rm=TRUE)
                 else names(which.max(table(x[x!=''])))
               replace(x, which(x %in% c(NA, '')), v1)
              }

df1[] <- lapply(df1, replaceNA)
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
      mutate_each(funs(replaceNA(.)))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(Col1= sample(c(LETTERS[1:3], ''), 10, replace=TRUE), 
       Col2=sample(c(1:5, NA), 10, replace=TRUE),
      Col3= sample(c(4:6, NA), 10, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```